# Étymologie et sens de "être fané" pour un humain

Tags: sens, étymologie

J'ai entendu dans la rue deux personnes françaises (non d'origine je pense) et l'une d'entre elles a dit à l'autre "t'es fané gros".
Je connais ce verbe pour les fleurs notamment mais c'est la première fois que je l'entends pour un "humain". Le dictionnaire ne me mentionne ni signification pour ça ni étymologie.

Je voulais donc savoir si cela existe bien dans la langue française et si oui est-ce la même étymologie que le verbe quand on parle des fleurs ?

Comment: *"Non d'origine française ?"* Tu es stéphanois ? ;-) Ne serait-ce pas plutôt : d'origine assurément lyonnaise ?

Comment: Réalisant que mon comm ci-dessus peut être pris en mauvaise part, je précise qu'il n'est aucune forme d'irrespect. Juste une allusion ironique à l'éternelle rivalité Lyon / Sainté dans la mesure où *fané* peut effectivement  s'entendre dans le lyonnais. http://www.topito.com/top-expressions-lyon-meilleure-ville-de-france

Comment: Un lyonnais qui revenait du dernier derby quoi... Deg!

Comment: Effectivement j'ai entendu cela à Lyon xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est le même mot qui est employé pour parler des végétaux ou pour des humains. L'adjectif *fané* vient du verbe *faner*, qui vient du bas latin *fenare* « retourner un végétal fauché pour le faire sécher ».

Je n'ai bien sûr pas consulté tous les dictionnaires mais ceux que je viens de consulter mentionnent que l'adjectif s'applique aussi bien aux plantes qu'aux humains, et même aux choses.

Définition de *faner* dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faner):

> Perdre de son éclat, de sa vigueur ou de sa beauté d'origine en raison du passage du temps.
>
> - Cette femme commence à se faner, se fane.

Dan le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fan%C3%A9) à l'adjectif *faner* :

> [En parlant d'une pers.] Visage, fille, beauté fané(e).
>
> - Castanier (...) apparaissait fané, ridé, vieilli, débile (Balzac, *Melmoth*).

Bien que ce soit plus rare on peut aussi employer cet adjectif pour des idées abstraites. Par exemple on peut dire que des souvenirs se sont fanés, c'est à dire qu'ils se sont un peu effacés avec le temps, qu'il se sont estompés.

Mais le mot a un sens particulier dans l'argot lyonnais, comme l'a signalé @aCOSwt dans son commentaire. Les Lyonnais l'emploie pour dire « dégoûté ». Ainsi s'explique mieux la juxtaposition des deux mots « gros » et « fanés ».

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse complète !

Comment: @Laure : Chuis vraiment deg! Tu connais pas Lyon ? Meilleure ville de France! ;-)

Comment: Je suis en train de le rajouter. Mais pour ce qui est de la meilleure ville de France là pas  d'accord. !  je n'aurais pas deviné que c'était de l'argot régional toute seule, peut-être y aurais-je pensé seulement si le PO avait dit qu'il l'avait entendu à Lyon....

Comment: Comment ? t'es stéphanoise aussi ? ;-) Blague dans le coin, si on se croise un jour, je t'offrirai avec plaisir un exemplaire de l'incomparable *Littré de la Grand'Côte*... une bible!

Comment: @aCOSwt On pourra échanger avec *Le petit précis de parler méridional*.  pas de lien publicitaire mais tu trouveras...

Answer (score 0):

Le dictionnaire utilisé n'était peut-être pas assez détaillé ; il existe un emploi figuré de cet adjectif qui le rend légitime dans l'usage que vous citez, lequel, soit dit en passant est d'un registre populaire allant du malpoli et insultant au bourru et amical selon la relation qui existe entre les deux personnes. On trouve ce sens dans le TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fan%C3%A9)) B. Au fig. Effacé, gommé par le temps. (Quasi-) synon. estompé, terni.
>
> - Cet intérêt si vif, mais si passager et si vite fané.  (SAINTE-BEUVE, Étude sur Virgile, 1857, p. 72)
> - Je te dirai quelque légende tendre et fanée.  (TOULET, Vers inéd., 1920, p. 10)
> - Irène avait de la France cette image un peu fanée, ridicule et fragile (MORAND, Lewis, 1924, p. 198)

L'adjectif dans ce sens figuré peut être appliqué à de nombreuses choses concrètes et abstraites. On le trouve appliqué à un être humain dans l'exemple suivant.

- Tout était vieux et fané en elle : les cheveux gris, mal tirés en arrière, les lourdes rides aux coins des lèvres, le regard fatigué par trop de larmes secrètes, les habits délavés et rapiécés...  Visages et regards au coeur de l'Evangile - Page 12
  https://books.google.fr › books
  Roland Jeanrenaud - 2003 -

Dans l'exemple suivant l'adjectif est appliqué à une personne par le biais d'une analogie.

- la femme … Celle-là était une extraordinaire créature : elle ressemblait à un vieil oiseau de paradis, fané, perdant ses plumes brillantes, mais étincelant encore d'un éclat de bijou faux, de joyau de théatre. (L'affaire Courilof
  https://books.google.fr › books
  Irène Némirovsky - 2005 -)

L'exemple suivant montre que l'adjectif peut être employé  pour décrire le corps.

- Étendue sur les couvertures de son lit, le torse relevé par deux oreillers peu épais, Olivia Sinclair avait le regard vitreux et le corps fané. À cinquante sept ans, elle en paraissait quatre-vingts. (- Lune de miel
  https://books.google.fr › books
  James Patterson - 2006 -)

Je ne trouve pas d'attestation pour le premier emploi figuré. L'étymologie du concept littéral, comme on peut le vérifier dans le TLFi au même lien que ci-dessus, remonte aux  environs de l'an 1200 et se trouve dans le  verbe « fener » (retourner l'herbe pour la faire sécher), lequel de nos jours s'écrit « faner ».